# Binding to value of property from inside style template failing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm having an issue with attempting to bind the `Fill` property of an `Elipse` (in a `ToggleButton` control) to a custom `DependencyProperty` of another control.
Below is the XAML code raising the "Property path is not valid" error - It's a Resource dictionary file for the `Expander` control.

The erroneous line:

```
Value="{Binding Path=(local:Expander.ToggleButtonMouseoverColor)}"
```

The first code block - the `MixSelectorExpanderButtonStyle` is attached to a style definition for an expander, seen in the second code block.

```
<Style x:Key="MixSelectorExpanderButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Circle" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=(local:Expander.ToggleButtonMouseoverColor)}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I'm confident the property is correct - in the same file, I am able to access the `ToggleButtonMouseoverColor` property without error:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Expander}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Status" Value="0">
           <Setter Property="ToggleButtonMouseoverColor" Value="{DynamicResource ZKGeneric_Highlight_MouseOver}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <ToggleButton style=""{StaticResource MixSelectorExpanderButtonStyle}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter.Value>
</Style>
```

When I remove the `local:` prefix from the path, the error changes to the property not being recognized or accessible.

If I name the style definition and change the binding to:

```
Value="{Binding Path=ExpanderStyle.ToggleButtonMouseoverColor}"
```

I am able to build and run it, however it appears to just be a null value.

Clearly I'm missing some syntax to properly point to the property, but this is the first time i have attempted to bind in such a convoluted manner.

If not, is there a more optimal way to define this behaviour?

Any help would be appreciated, in the meantime, I shall attempt to consult my WPF programmer's reference.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention, I have also been trying to use `Value="{Binding ToggleButtonMouseoverColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"`, among other variations, but can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want this, although it sounds like you've potentially tried it? I have no idea why it wouldn't work...

```
Value="{Binding ToggleButtonMouseoverColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Expander}}}"
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, I guess i needed to specify the ancestor type